# Use WHERE clause when execute stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've stored procedure to view data transaction by joining other tabel

```
create procedure prRecapitulation
as
begin
    SELECT      a.TransactionID,
                a.Buyer_Code,
                a.Date_Transaction,
                b.NuggetID,
                SUM(b.Qty) as Qty,
                SUM(b.Sub_Total) as Sub_Total,
                SUM(a.Total_Price) as Total_Price
    FROM        Transactions a JOIN DetailTransaction b On a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
    WHERE       DAY(a.Date_Transaction) = 21 AND MONTH(a.Date_Transaction) = 01 AND YEAR(a.Date_Transaction) = 2017
    GROUP BY    a.TransactionID, a.Buyer_Code, a.Date_Transaction, b.NuggetID
    ORDER BY    a.Date_Transaction DESC
end
```

But i've thinking to remove WHERE clause from stored procedure because sometime (maybe) the conditions will change based on number 21, 01 and 2017.

here's my expectation query

```
exec prRecapitulation
where DAY(a.Date_Transaction) = 21
```

So the procedure can display the transaction based on date 21 or use `MONTH()` or `YEAR()` function as well.

Comment: You can't do it. You have to use parameters instead

Comment: Why not just add a parameter to your procedure with a.Date_Transaction and set the WHERE ... = your parameter? I don't see why you're using day, month & year...?

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a table valued function instead of procedure with three input parameters. It will be easy to call and join with tables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Udf_prrecapitulation(@day   tinyint,
                                     @month tinyint,
                                     @year  smallint)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT a.TransactionID,
              a.Buyer_Code,
              a.Date_Transaction,
              b.NuggetID,
              Sum(b.Qty)         AS Qty,
              Sum(b.Sub_Total)   AS Sub_Total,
              Sum(a.Total_Price) AS Total_Price
       FROM   Transactions a
              JOIN DetailTransaction b
                ON a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
       WHERE  ( Day(a.Date_Transaction) = @day
                 OR @day IS NULL )
              AND ( Month(a.Date_Transaction) = @month
                     OR @month IS NULL )
              AND ( Year(a.Date_Transaction) = @year
                     OR @year IS NULL )
       GROUP  BY a.TransactionID,
                 a.Buyer_Code,
                 a.Date_Transaction,
                 b.NuggetID)
```

To call

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Udf_prrecapitulation(21, 1, 2017)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass in the values as parameters:

```
create procedure prRecapitulation (
    @year int,
    @month int,
    @day int
) as
begin
    SELECT a.TransactionID, a.Buyer_Code, a.Date_Transaction, b.NuggetID,
           SUM(b.Qty) as Qty, SUM(b.Sub_Total) as Sub_Total,
           SUM(a.Total_Price) as Total_Price
    FROM Transactions a JOIN
         DetailTransaction b
         On a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
    WHERE DAY(a.Date_Transaction) = @day AND
          MONTH(a.Date_Transaction) = @month AND
          YEAR(a.Date_Transaction) = @year
    GROUP BY a.TransactionID, a.Buyer_Code, a.Date_Transaction, b.NuggetID
    ORDER BY a.Date_Transaction DESC
end;
```

Then call with the explicit values:

```
exec prRecapitulation(2017, 1, 21);
```

You can also give the parameters default values, if you want.

EDIT:

For this type of query, I would actually encourage you to provide the dates using the `date` data type:

```
create procedure prRecapitulation (
    @date date
) as
begin
    SELECT a.TransactionID, a.Buyer_Code, a.Date_Transaction, b.NuggetID,
           SUM(b.Qty) as Qty, SUM(b.Sub_Total) as Sub_Total,
           SUM(a.Total_Price) as Total_Price
    FROM Transactions a JOIN
         DetailTransaction b
         On a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
    WHERE a.Date_Transaction = @date
    GROUP BY a.TransactionID, a.Buyer_Code, a.Date_Transaction, b.NuggetID
    ORDER BY a.Date_Transaction DESC
end;
```

You can call it using:

```
exec prRecapitulation('2017-01-21');
```

You can also modify the stored procedure to provide two dates, which can be used as a range.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
   'server=(local);trusted_connection=yes', 'EXEC prRecapitulation') 
 where DAY(a.Date_Transaction) = 21
```

Comment: *trusted_connection=yes* you are assuming a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

A better method that will use an appropriate index (and be more efficient):

```
create procedure prRecapitulation 
(
    @year int,
    @month int,
    @day int
) 
as
begin
    declare @date as date
    set @date = cast(cast(@year as char(4)) + '-' + cast(@month as char(2)) + '-' + cast(@day as char(2)) as date)
    SELECT     
        a.TransactionID,
        a.Buyer_Code,
        a.Date_Transaction,
        b.NuggetID,
        Qty = SUM(b.Qty),
        Sub_Total = SUM(b.Sub_Total),
        Total_Price = SUM(a.Total_Price)
    FROM 
        Transactions a 
        JOIN DetailTransaction b ON a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
    WHERE
        a.Date_Transaction between @date and Dateadd(ms, -3.33, Dateadd(day, 1, @date))
    GROUP BY 
        a.TransactionID, a.Buyer_Code, a.Date_Transaction, b.NuggetID
    ORDER BY 
        a.Date_Transaction DESC
end;
```

or better still, simply pass in a date as a parameter.

Comment: `Date_Transaction  >= @date and Date_Transaction < Dateadd(dd,1,@date)` This could be more meaningful and same as op's approach if there is `time` part present in `Date_Transaction`